# Obtaining a list of words from a GNU aspell dictionary

Tags: language, utf-8, aspell

I downloaded the aspell package for Bengali language dictionary support. From the tarball, I was able to isolate the bn.wl file, which is simply a list of about 100,000 words, one on each line.

The problem is that the encoding is apparently is13194-bn, and any text editor I open the file with is showing garbage (one garbage-word per line). It's probably expecting utf8 or something.

How can I convert this file to readable form? I tried using iconv but it apparently can't recognize the encoding.

Comment: did you try using aspell itself to provide the word list:  `aspell -l bn dump master` ?

Comment: I was getting an error when I tried that on my Ubuntu machine, but I tried it on a Fedora machine and it worked! Thanks a lot! Can you post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aspell itself to provide the word list in a readable format:

```
aspell -l bn dump master
```

The -l switch targets a specific dictionary, if it is absent, then the default dictionary is chosen.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with aspell install but without having installed the 'bn' language? For example, by pointing aspell to the location of a downloaded aspell dictionary (a .cwl file).